# How to push into an array corresponding to the body i'm passing to the api?

Tags: reactjs

I have a post api which accepts a body(id) and returns an array.While returning that array i'm mapping through the array and pushing the elements into a new array(that's what i want because i need some additional elements). The problem is when i change the api body and search for new datas the new datas is getting pushed to the same array which consists of previous result.

How to push into an array corresponding to the body i'm passing to the api.(i.e, say for example if i pass id-10 to the api and pushed my results to an array.Then i pass id 13 to the api and what i need is to clear the previous array and push new items corresponding to the id)

This is what i did

```
   axios.post(domain.BASE_URL + "VoyageDetails/GetVoyageDetails", { 
         VoyageId: this.VoyageID.value }) 
        .then(response => { 
        if (response.data.statusCode === 200) { 
        this.setState({ DataSet3: response.data.items }); 
        this.state.DataSet3.map(item => { 
        this.state.DataSet4.push({ id: item.id, srno: item.srno, voyageId: 
        item.voyageId, voyageNo: item.voyageNo, portId: item.portId, 
        portName: item.portName, eta: item.eta, etb: item.etb, ets: 
        item.ets, ata: item.ata, atb: item.atb, ats: item.ats, eta_time: 
        item.eta.toLocaleTimeString(), etb_time: 
        item.etb.toLocaleTimeString(), ets_time: 
        item.ets.toLocaleTimeString(), ata_time: new 
        Date(item.ata).toLocaleTimeString(), atb_time: new 
        Date(item.atb).toLocaleTimeString(), ats_time: new Date(item.ats).toLocaleTimeString(), remarks: item.remarks, recordVersion: item.recordVersion }); }); 
        this.setState({ DataSet4: this.state.DataSet4 }); 
        } 
        else if (response.data.statusCode === 404) { this.setState({ DataSet4: [] }); 
        } 
        });
```